# How to I get mods to my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I've downloaded a free Minecraft server from https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server and it works! I can play on the server. But even if I start up Minecraft with Forge, the mods won't work.

For example, I have WorldEdit. When I type in `//wand` it says *Unknown command*. And when I place down furniture, they pop up for a second and then disappear.
Is there any way to get mods in to your own Minecraft server?

Comment: Serverside mods are handled differently. You should get something like [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/) and install WorldEdit as a [plugin](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit).

Comment: I think this isn't technical support, but ultimately asking how servers work (with or without mods). Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4):

Client-Side Forge and Server-Side forge are two different things; Client side is only on your computer, while server-side is on a server, and requires everyone to have the mods to join. If you would like to setup a forge server, install the server side version from the official website.

https://files.minecraftforge.net/